# Travis CI build failed with weird errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, build, travis-ci

[image]

I literally have no idea why `npm install` trys to open some files in `./staging` path, because it doesn't have to be hidden folder or files. It worked well when I was working on the project but It doesn't work after I deploy the project with those errors. what should I do?

actual travis ci link: https://travis-ci.org/imkimchi/ni/jobs/325242673

Comment: Can you post your `.travis.yml` and any other build information?

Comment: @colinharris05 I just updated post with a link. take a look :)